# jQuery - Add to Serialized Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, serializearray

I've tried various ways to add to my serialized array, but I keep running into the following issues:

My first attempt results in: `[object Object]&username=1` being sent.

```
var vals = {};

$.each($('#my-form').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
  vals[field.name] = field.value;
});

$.ajax({
  url: "https://example.com",
  type: "POST",
  data: vals + "&username=1",
  complete: function(){
    alert("Success")
  }
});
```

My second attempt results in: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: vals.push is not a function`

```
var vals = {};

$.each($('#my-form').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
   vals[field.name] = field.value;
 });

vals.push({name: 'username', value: 1});

$.ajax({
  url: "https://example.com",
  type: "POST",
  data: vals,
  complete: function(){
    alert("Success")
  }
});
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `vals` is  an Object which do not push method attached to it

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'm working with an object, not an array.  smh.  `vals.username = 1;` is what works in this case.  Thank you, @CodeManiac.

Comment: try $.param(vals) + "&username=1" for this issue [object Object]&username=1